# Can I set thresholds for 74HC14N (6 NOT gates)? and use as schmitt trigger

Tags: digital-logic, analog, noise, signal-processing

I'm trying to convert sine-like wave from IR sensor(quadrature wheel encoder) into square one. Can I make it with 74HC14N(set some fancy RC configuration) or should I use op-amp configuration to be able to set thresholds?

here Y is 5 volts scaled to 1024(arduino). So it's around 0.4-3.4 volts.
[image: sine waves]

Here is another example and what I need to get
[image]
[image]

Or if you know DIY guides for quadrature wheel encoder that solves this issue, can you please share with me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Red line at second plot shows very different minimums and maximums. 3rd minimum value is very close to last maximum. It seems you should discover nature of this noise and eliminate it to have good results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thresholds for the 74HC14 can not be modified externally from the chip.  The thresholds actually vary quite a bit, as shown  in the following table from the datasheet:

[image]

With a 6v supply, it appears the maximum low threshold V<sub>T-</sub> (3.2v) can supposedly be greater than the minimum high threshold V<sub>T+</sub> (2.1v), however this is actually overridden by the last parameter V<sub>T+</sub> - V<sub>T-</sub> which guarantees the minimum separation of 0.5v.  However as one can see, there is not much control over these values.

However you can add a precise amount of hysteresis to a comparator using the following circuit:

[image]

where V2 is the high threshold value (turn off) and V1 is the low threshold (turn on).

The resistor values are calculated using the following relationships:

$$\frac{R3}{R1} = \frac{V1}{V2 - V1}$$

$$\frac{R2}{R1} = \frac{V1}{Vref - V2}$$

The calculations are made much simpler using [this online calculator](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/compkeisan.htm).

And here are some [additional circuit notes](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020/tidu020.pdf) from TI about adding hysteresis to comparators.

If one doesn't have a comparator available, an op-amp can be substituted, but it is not as satisfactory as discussed [here](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-849.pdf).  Nevertheless, the [datasheet for the LM324](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/LM324-D.PDF) even includes a circuit for using it as a comparator with hysteresis:

[image]

quite similar to the one shown earlier (just no resistor from the + input to ground).

Comment: Is LM324 suitable for this? But don't want to make virtual ground with additional battery.. thanks anyway. so not-gates is no use here?

Comment: Thank you for explaining datasheet. It was tricky for me to understand this table.

Comment: The LM324 is an op-amp.  You want to use a comparator.  The TI circuit notes I referenced used a TLV3201 (which is a surface mount device), but most any single-supply comparator will do that has rail-to-rail inputs.  As an example, the [MCP6546](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21714G.pdf) is available in a single, dual, or quad DIP packages.

Comment: It's just that I don't have comparators. Maybe NE555 or Attiny85 will do job? Guess Attiny85 will do what I've done in Mathematica converting sines into squares..

Comment: @a_vasilkov NE555 can't be used, neither can the comparator inside the Attiny85 since you can't get to the output to add hysteresis.  However see my revised answer which includes a circuit for the LM324, and an app note about using op-amps as comparators.